Removed Python2.7 executable and now I can't uninstall it
I have Ubuntu 22.04.4lts and I installed python3.11.7 and python2.7.18. I tried to uninstall python2.7 with sudo apt remove python2 python2-pip but I got this message:
E: Unable to locate package python2-pip

So I asked Chatgpt and basically it recommended me to do sudo rm -rf /usr/bin/python2.7.
Now that the executable is removed, I can't open python2, but I can't reinstall it either because in the command line says that no files are being installed.
I tried re-install python 2.7 with
sudo apt install python2.7

to see if it can restore the executable but it gives errors with python-pip package. Then I tried to delete the python2.7 "leftovers" with
sudo apt remove python2.7 

which gives me errors again with python-pip:
dpkg: error processing package python-pip (--remove):
 the installed python-pip pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 127
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python-pip.postinst: 6: pycompile: not found
dpkg: error cleaning up:
 the installed python-pip post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python-pip
Process was stopped because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Then I tried to install python-pip to see if I could uninstall python2 after:
sudo apt install --reinstall python-pip

but gives: E: Internal Error, No file name for python-pip:amd64. Then I tried
sudo apt --fix-broken install

gives: error processing python-pip
I really have no idea what to do and I'm pretty new on Linux command line. I don't know if all these problems are due to the missing python2 executable or if python-pip errors are not related to it. But as far as I know, python2 was working well with "pip2" commands before I messed the executable. Please help me delete Python2 .

If ChatGPT tells you to shoot yourself in the head, would you do it? You have a responsibility to apply common sense and critical thinking when taking instructions from a language model trained by reading things written by Internet randos just as much as you do when taking instructions from Internet randos directly.

More to the point, apt and dpkg have safety features that deliberately make it hard to break your system without using --force-type parameters. When you use rm, you're bypassing the safeties. Don't do that. A lot of Linux distros don't allow the Python version they came with to be installed at all, because the distro's own machinery depends on that Python release and so uninstalling that specific version of Python innately breaks the distro. The right answer is not to force things with rm or dpkg --force but rather just to leave the old packages there.

...if your distro provides Python 2.7, that makes no difference at all to a project you're doing with Python 3.11. It's not a problem in the first place, much less one you need to fix. Leave the distro-provided software alone; install new things in addition to it as and when you need to, but don't try to uninstall or replace it.

Anyhow, reinstall python2.7 itself first; only after you've done that, worry about pip. dpkg -i --force-all if you've downloaded the Python 2.7 package is a place to start.

maybe you will have to reinstall Linux. And don't delete python2.

@CharlesDuffy Hi there. Yeah you're 100% right about chatgpt. I followed it out of ignorance and a bit of desperation at that point. But my case is not that as you're thinking. Python 2.7 didn't come by distro, I downloaded it since I need it to run a simulation program I need for Uni. Thing is it didn't work well so I wanted to uninstall and reinstall. But then I screwed it up even more. I tried to reinstall python2 with sudo apt install python2 and sudo apt-get install --reinstall python2.7 but both give me errors that basically say my executable is missing. :(

Right, that's why I was telling you to use dpkg directly for the reinstall, and to be ready to use --force arguments to make it go through even if some of the preinstall/postinstall bits fail. (Mind, using --force is a place where you need to have your brain turned on and pay attention to the details of the messages; don't do it just because I told you to without actually reading the details of the errors you're overriding and being sure you agree that it's safe to ignore them)

Again, though, reinstall python2 itself first, before you try to do anything with the package for pip.
